# htaccess - removal of extension - allow or force trailing slashes without breaking relative links

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, hyperlink

and thanks in advance for any help!

What I'm trying to achieve is this: I would like to remove the file extension from file names using htaccess -  which is what I've done. However, when a user points their browser to a file without an extension and adds a trailing slash I get a page not found error. I found some code which corrected this, however, when I implemented the code, it broke my relative links to CSS and jQuery located in the head.

I really would rather like to keep relative links to all my files, but would also like to allow trailing slashes for individual files.

Is this possible?

My site is here: `http://www.getagig.info`

And my current htaccess code (which only removes extensions is below).

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php
```

Edit: I understand from your comment below what your issue is, but I've taken a look at your site, and I'm a little confused why you're trying to do it this way.

From what I understand, all you really want is for yourwebsite.com/filename or yourwebsite.com/filename/ to use filename.php, in which case you're better off using an .htaccess rule like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ $1.php
```

This should still allow your CSS and JS files to load, as well as any file or directory that physically exists on your server. If you do not want people to physically call "filename.php", then you can set-up a separate rule for that.

Comment: I thought so to at first but the problem with this is that the second `RewriteCond` will still fail (as there is no `filename/.php` file...

Comment: what about getting htaccess to ignore .css .js files?

Comment: @Czechnology: Okay, I see what your problem is. I've edited my answer above with an additional suggestion. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to test if the file exists in **RewriteCond** if you have `/` appended to your url.

Only solution I can think of here would be using htaccess to redirect to some php file which will sort things out:

.htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ route.php?url=$1
```

.php file

```
<?php

$url = $_GET['url'];

if (strpos($url, '..') !== false || strpos($url, '/') !== false) {
  echo "No relative urls!";

} else if (file_exists($url)) {
  // do what you want - require or redirect to the requested file

} else {
  // requested file does not exist
}
```

Comment: Is it not possible to get htaccess to ignore .css and .js files?

Comment: What do you mean, "ignore"? If you refer to the RewriteRule, you could expand the RewriteCond like this:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(php|css|js)$`.

Comment: will this convert all foo.php to /foo but leave .css and .js alone?

Comment: Combined with what is above in my code it would route all urls, that are 1) not pointing to a directory and 2) do not end with .php, .css or .js, to `route.php`, _without_ the optional trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the line:

```
<BASE href="http://www.sitename.com/">
```

to my page inside the `<head>` tag works great for me. It can be coded even a PHP function to automatize this so you don't have to bother with copy/paste on other occasions.

**Update:**

```
<?php
$BaseDir = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"], 0, strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);
?>

<head>
...
<BASE href="<?php echo $BaseDir; ?>">
...
</head>
```